# Are there any standards for naming variables to indicate that they are being modified by reference in Java?

Tags: java, pass-by-reference, naming

It is not ideal but I have a function (private) that edits an object by reference. Looks like this, where `payload` is the object that is mutated:

```
void extractDataForConfigIntoPayload(Map<K,V> payload, Object obj1, ..) {
   // mutate payload purposefully 
}
```

I'm trying to write this function with no comments while keeping it as descriptive as possible. What is a good convention for naming variables like `payload` that are modified by reference as a deliberate side effect to the method? In this very specific situation, it seems C++'s demanding syntax helps because pointers are clearly pointers, addresses are clearly addresses, and so forth.

Comment: `payloadToMutate`, or `payloadByRef`.  No, there are no standards for this, just as there are few standards for naming variables in general.

Comment: `Ref` at the end of the name, but I don't see why you'd need to do this, I'd recommend using an immutable approach (AKA create a new copy)

Comment: In Java, _all_ objects are passed by value; there is no such thing as pass by reference. You can, however, change the object that the passed value refers to.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to make it clear is to *not modify the `payload` variable* and then create inside the function a new `Map` and return the new `Map`.

Example:

```
Map<K, V> extractDataForConfigIntoPayload(Map<K,V> payload, Object obj1, ..) {
   // create new map and return the new map, leaving payload untouched
   return myNewMap; 
}
```

Be aware that this kind of coding, while prioritizing clean code, will not be as efficient as just modifying the original `payload` map.

Comment: Even better would be to use Guava `ImmutableMap` instead of just `Map` as parameter type.

Comment: This is good advice in theory. In practice, you may not need to retain the previous value of the map but you may need to squeeze out the last nanosecond of your very high performance application and don't want the overhead of unnecessarily copying a whole map just to change one value. So this depends on your application. Sometimes your advice should be followed, but not for all types of application.

Comment: Indeed, @k314159. Will add a note.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of the idea of sacrificing efficiency over clean code. They can coexist in the same method.

Comment: Since there's no convention for naming the variable, I prefer to make it clear in the method signature.

Answer (score 0):

There are no real naming conventions for that. You can not mark those parameter that will be modified by the method. However, you can mark those arguments which shall not be modified as `final`.

For instance:

```
void extractDataForConfigIntoPayload(Map<K,V> payload, final Object obj1, ..)  {
   // mutate payload purposefully 
}
```

This will ensure that you'll not accidentally modify objects which are supposed to be immutable.

Comment: Marking obj1 as final will not guarantee that the object itself will not be modified; it only guarantees that the method will not change the variable obj1 to refer to a different object, which only has an effect inside the method body and is therefore nothing but an implementation detail that the caller of the method does not need to know about.